# Asp.Net Web Service 415 Unsupported Media Type error

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have done some changes and now getting 415 Unsupported Media Type.
I am posting the updated code.
My Web Service Interface.

Service/IWebService.cs

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "http://localhost:50571/Service/WebService.svc/hello/say")]
    string hello(Deneme deneme );

 [DataContract]
public class Deneme
{
    [DataMember]
    public string say { get; set; }
}
```

My Web Service.
Service/WebService.svc

```
 [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =    AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class WebService : IWebService
{
    public string hello(Deneme deneme) {
        return deneme.say;
    }
```

Client Side Code.
in Login.aspx

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Service/WebService.svc/hello',
        data: { 'say': 'sdfs' },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (s) {
            alert(s.d);
        }
    });
```

Web Config

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
      <service name="TETP.Service.WebService">
          <endpoint address=""
            behaviorConfiguration=""
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="TETP.Service.IWebService" />
      </service>
  </services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors >
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:50571/Service/WebService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWebService" contract="TETP.Service.IWebService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IWebService" />
</client>
```

i used to get 400 bad request error. Now i get 415 Unsupported Media Type error Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you data request might need quotes differently than what you tried but I am not sure. I would suggest adding an alert of your data before the call to debug it. See below..

```
var mData = "{userName:'" + $('#usernametxtbx').val() + "',password:'" + $('#passwordtxtbx').val() + "'}";
alert(mData);
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Service/WebService.svc/Login',
        data:{userName:$('#usernametxtbx').val(),password:$('#passwordtxtbx').val()},
        dataType: 'application/json; content=utf-8',
        contentType: 'json',
        success: function (res) {
        if(res.d == true)
            window.location.replace(ResolveUrl('Default.aspx'));
            else
                window.location.replace(ResolveUrl('Login.aspx'));
        }
    });
```

Comment: this is not it. im sending json i could as well just do var data = {userName:$('#usernametxtbx').val()} and send the data